# Error installing psycopg2 on Windows using pip and virtualenv

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, virtualenv, pip

I'm following Heroku's "Getting started with Django on Heroku" article and am getting a long series of errors on "pip install psycopg2".  Django 1.4.3 and PostgreSQL 9.2.2 are already installed, and yes, the postgres \bin\ directory is on the PATH.

[image: Command window output from attempting to install psycopg2]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't look like Psycopg on Windows is as simple as using pip.  The Psycopg website recommends using [these Windows builds](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/).

Comment: Thanks - that works to install psycopg2 globally (`>>>import psycopg2` works globally and in the virtualenv), but the goal is to install in the virtualenv only. Is there a way to copy the global installation into my virtualenv?  Copying from site-packages to site-packages results in an ImportError.

Comment: The download link I posted makes a brief mention of virtualenv, see if that helps.

Comment: @Theron Luhn: It doesn't support 64 bit version

Answer (score 0):

As a windows users running through the Python Getting Started tutorial on Heroku I ran into a similar issue.  I found pycopg2 here: http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/

And then used easy_install in the virtual env directory.